# System freezes, apt-cache running 100% for an hour?

Tags: apt, 18.04, freeze, apt-cache

Sorry if I'm overdoing the details. I'm new to the forum, that or I have another account I never knew about.

I know the community prefers questions that can be answered, and I'm hoping I can get an answer, but this is turning out to be a mystery. I suspect my problem is being caused by apt-cache, but I'm at a loss for what may cause apt-cache to hang, so to put it short, apt-cache hanging and causing crashes is really my question. Details below if needed.

Backstory: I have 18.04 LTS for desktop and gaming. For some while now, I've been investigating a freeze that happens semi-randomly. I notice if I let it run for a few days, it just locks up, sometimes even in half a day. The state that it ends up in is a completely broken state where nothing responds. USB, PS/2, Ethernet, audio is repeating if it was playing, the works. I did some overclocking in the past but this happens with stock settings and all of my hardware survives stress tests. I now stay at stock settings on my mobo until I can cure this problem.

After thorough investigation and having no backups in a known-good state, I finally resorted to just letting it freeze and catching the screen with htop running. The offender seems to be apt-cache, as it used 100% of a CPU core and ran for over 58 minutes. Steam also used a whole core at the time but I expect that from Valve. What I don't expect is apt-cache running the policy command for an hour, so I think something's causing it to hang until the whole system locks. When I run the same command, however, it runs and quits just fine, and it only seems to hang like this in this random occurrence when it is run automatically. I would appreciate anything that can help in my investigation, as I'd prefer not to reformat and set everything back up if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the process tree for apt-cache, with a command like `pstree -p`, or just `ps auxf`. Then try and figure out why apt-cache is even running & tell it not to, or reconfigure it, or maybe upgrade it... (you could've killed it too, instead of let it hog the cpu for an hour).

Finding the right PID could use `pgrep`, and some options of pstree to show parent(s), (p)ids, (a)rguments, VT100 (l)ine characters:

```
pstree PID -s -p -a -G -l
```

<sup>Source: https://superuser.com/questions/1204006/how-to-find-ancestor-chain-of-a-process/1204263#1204263</sup>

Comment: In case I do catch it before the system locks, that will help. I have so far only come home to a locked up machine since setting up htop to wait for the occurrence. (Sorry that I didn't explain that well enough.) Though in hindsight I'm starting to think I may be asking for a miracle...

Comment: It really shouldn't be freezing from any program just running... Just guessing but maybe a heatsink or fan isn't working well & it's overheating? If the computer's nearly at idle while you're away, you could consider limiting the cpu frequency (with cpufreq-utils) if your system supports it, or if it's only the one program (apt-cache) there are other programs that could monitor it and limit it's cpu usage if it gets above a %